# Spring Beans: Call a specific class method after instantiation

Tags: spring, dependency-injection

I have 2 classes A & B. Booth are from some 3rd party package.

I have something like this in code

```
A objA = new objA;
objA.registerModule(new B());
```

Now I was thinking of @Autowiring A in the code. Is there a way to create a bean of A and B and call registerModule of class A & pass in reference to B in its bean?

Something like this:

```
<bean id="classB" class = ... />
<bean id="classA>
/*pass in reference to B */
</bean>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes there is, take a look at: [MethodInvokingFactoryBean](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/MethodInvokingFactoryBean.html)

In your case it should be something like this:

```
<bean id="classB" class = "com.company.B"/>
<bean id="classA" class = "com.company.A"/>

<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean">
    <property name="targetObject" ref="classA"/>
    <property name="targetMethod" value="registerModule"/>
    <property name="arguments">
        <list>classB</list>
    </property>
</bean>
```